# How to bind event from child to parent component in Angular 2+ in ngSwitch

Tags: javascript, angular, event-binding

My parent component calls the child component with a ngSwitch case:

```
<div *ngSwitchDefault>
   <app-child-comp (toggleHelp)="toggleHelp($event)"></app-child-comp>
</div>
```

And in the child component:

```
@Output() toggleHelp = new EventEmitter();
this.toggleHelp.emit(true);
```

And in the parent component:

```
toggleHelp() {
  console.log('event fired');
}
```

So far no success.
If I call the component without `ngSwitch`, then it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not enough code. Did you define `@Output` in child component? Did you define `toggleHelp` method in parent component

Comment: provide full code of thr parent component and child component

Comment: As per your code, `(toggleHelp)="showHideIcon($event)"`.

Comment: Hi, updated the code .. sorry changed showHideIcon to toggleHelp... nothing

Comment: @MysterX yes i did and modified the code..as I told you guys.. this works fine if I remove the ngSwitch

Comment: Could not reproduce issue. Working fine here bro.

Comment: @SangwinGawande did you put the child component in a switch case

Comment: Yes I did. `<div [ngSwitch]="valuess">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">11111111111111111</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <app-child (toggleHelp)="toggleHelp($event)">
      
    </app-child>
  </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

Parent HTML :

```
<div [ngSwitch]="valuess">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">11111111111111111</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>
    <app-child (toggleHelp)="toggleHelp($event)">

    </app-child>
  </div>
</div>
<a (click)="changeValue()">valuess</a>
```

Parent TS :

```
valuess = 1;
toggleHelp(evt) {
    console.log('event fired',evt);
}
changeValue(){
    this.valuess = 2;
}
```

Child HTML :

```
 <a (click)="toggleHelpCall()">toggleHelp</a>
```

Child TS  :

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() toggleHelp = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    toggleHelpCall() {
        this.toggleHelp.emit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @WhoIsCarlo -Glad I could help.